# Re-cursing through folder, while maintaining nested loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Looking to make the following code recurse through sub-folders.
It works as I want it to right now, but I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around recursing through subfolders with the same for/if statements I already have in place. More of a logic block, thanks in advance.

```
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path

#search through entire path given as parameter, recursive
runtimepath = sys.argv
currenttime = "output" + (str(datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y-%H%M") + ".txt"))

print ("File", currenttime, "being generated.")

output_file = open(os.path.join(runtimepath[1], currenttime), "w")

ext_list =  [
"txt","webm","mkv","flv","vob","ogv","ogg","drc","gif","gifv","mng",
"avi","mts","m2ts","mov","qt","wmv","yuv","rm","rmvb","asf","amv","mp4","m4p","m4v",
"mpg","mp2","mpeg","mpe","mpv","m2v","svi","3gp","3g2","mxf","roq","nsv","flv","f4v",
"f4p","f4a","f4b","mp3"
]

for f in os.listdir(runtimepath[1]) :
    for extension in ext_list:
        if f.endswith(extension) == True :
            #print(f)
            temp_string = os.path.join(runtimepath[1],f)
            print (temp_string)
            output_file.write(temp_string)
            output_file.write("\n")

output_file.close();
```

Comment: Consider `os.walk` instead of `os.listdir`: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: I get this if I do that: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Comment: use `os.walk` to get it. But if you need to do it on your own then put `for ... in os.listdir` in function and execute it inside `for ... in os.listdir` when you get subfolder.

Comment: read documentation for `os.walk` it gives tuple with 3 values - root, all files and all subfolder. You have to get files and use nested `for` loop to check every file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. The below served my needs:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(runtimepath[1]):
    for file in files:
        for extension in ext_list:
            if file.endswith(extension) == True:
                print(file)
                temp_string = os.path.join(runtimepath[1],file)
                print (temp_string)
                output_file.write(temp_string)
                output_file.write("\n")
```